# When compiled c function from different platforms and got symbols in difference with __kernel__

Tags: android, c, undefined-symbol

I tried to compile open source library `nmap` for the android platform.

In ubuntu, I used ndk tookchain to build libnetutil and get `libnetutil.a`.
With nm, I lookup symbol for fuction:
`int mac_cache_get(const struct sockaddr_storage *ss, u8 *mac);`
I got symbol `_Z13mac_cache_getPK25__kernel_sockaddr_storagePh`.

But on Mac， I use Android Studio to writed a simple android c++ demo and call the fuction `mac_cache_get`.

It will report undefined reference to `mac_cache_get(sockaddr_storage const*, unsigned char*)` link error.

With `nm` the `.o` file, it try to call the function with symbol:
`_Z13mac_cache_getPK16sockaddr_storagePh`.

So the symbol has littel difference with `_Z13mac_cache_getPK25__kernel_sockaddr_storagePh` and `_Z13mac_cache_getPK16sockaddr_storagePh`.

I don't know whether the difference cause the link error, if yes, how to fix the difference?

Comment: It's not something I know, but have you tried liking with `libnetutil`? That is, add `-lnetutil` when compiling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do add -lnetutil and it linked the libenetutil.a lib file from build output.

Comment: Hmm, and still the same output? Perhaps it's best if you show your full makefile.

Comment: libnetutil makefile generated from configure.
https://github.com/raulftang/nmapbuild/blob/main/Makefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake to use the compiler for linux platform which will generate the symbol with **kernel** prefix for sockaddr_storage parameter.

The compiler for android platform will generate the symbol without **kernel** prefix.

Thanks for all.